# Copying Array to another Array

Tags: java, arrays, copy

im trying to copy the contents of one array to another without pointing to the same memory, but i cant.

My Code:

```
class cPrueba {
    private float fvalor;

    public float getFvalor() {
        return fvalor;
    }

    public void setFvalor(float fvalor) {
        this.fvalor = fvalor;
    }
}

List<cPrueba> tListaPrueba = new ArrayList<cPrueba>();
List<cPrueba> tListaPrueba2 = new ArrayList<cPrueba>();

cPrueba tPrueba = new cPrueba();
tPrueba.setFvalor(50);
tListaPrueba.add(tPrueba);

tListaPrueba2.addAll(tListaPrueba);
tListaPrueba2.get(0).setFvalor(100);

System.out.println(tListaPrueba.get(0).getFvalor());
```

The result is "100.0" ....

Still pointing to the same object... Any short way to copy ? (without  for(..){})

EDIT:

```
class cPrueba implements Cloneable {
    private float fvalor;

    public float getFvalor() {
        return fvalor;
    }

    public void setFvalor(float fvalor) {
        this.fvalor = fvalor;
    }

    public cPrueba clone() {
        return this.clone();
    }
}

List<cPrueba> tListaPrueba = new ArrayList<cPrueba>();
List<cPrueba> tListaPrueba2 = new ArrayList<cPrueba>();

cPrueba tPrueba = new cPrueba();
tPrueba.setFvalor(50);
tListaPrueba.add(tPrueba);

for ( cPrueba cp : tListaPrueba )
    tListaPrueba2.add(cp);

tListaPrueba2.get(0).setFvalor(100);

System.out.println(tListaPrueba.get(0).getFvalor());
```

Still get 100...

Comment: You'll have to clone all objects, and thus to loop over them.

Comment: An **array** or `ArrayList`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like dystroy said, you'll need to pass through the loop and clone all of the objects, like this:

```
List<cPrueba> newList = new ArrayList<cPrueba>();
for ( cPrueba cp : oldList )
    newList.add(cp.clone());
```

And that's assuming your object implements Cloneable, or at least has a method called clone.

So no, there is no short way (unless you write your own static method), but it is possible.

EDIT
You need your clone method to return a new cPrueba:

```
public cPrueba clone() {
    cPrueba c = new cPrueba();
    c.setFvalor(this.getFvalor());
    return c;
}
```

Also, make sure you call `cp.clone()` in your for loop; don't just pass cp to the add method. e.g., change

```
tListaPrueba2.add(cp);
```

to

```
tListaPrueba2.add(cp.clone());
```

Answer (score 5):

There is no way to "deepcopy" an array, or any kind of `Collection` (which includes `List`) or even `Map` if your object itself does not have deep copy support (for instance, via a copy constructor).

So, to your question:

> Any short way to copy ? (without for(..){})

the answer is no.

Of course, if your objects are immutable, this is not a concern.

Answer (score 0):

vanilla Java can't do this for you.

but by adding some spice you can get it done with the Dozer framework:

http://dozer.sourceforge.net/